# Maintaining a standard set of data in centralised place and used by one or more salesforce orgs

Tags: data

I have a requirement to use a standard set of data that is the same for every Salesforce org.

The standard data is huge in size and rarely changes. However, each customer has their own dedicated org that will be using this data.

My question is, if I store the data in Salesforce for every org, then the data is duplicated across all the orgs and any changes will require updating or deleting the data in every org. I need a solution to keep this data in a centralized place so that multiple orgs can use it.

I also need to consider the governor limits for API calls or any other factors.

Can anyone suggest the best way to manage this?

**Adding some insight:**
Data is huge in size is around 0.2 millions , Data is structured and fits in tables, data changes periodically based on the agency needs. I am not thinking about packaging as of now though the data is in structure and placed in the table. This data is used to show on the UI for selections in the combo box/drop down in LWC

Comment: "data is huge in size" - could you add a ballpark figure to your question? Is this data richly structured or plain ("fits in tables", better for static resources etc.)? Have you considered a packaging mechanism? Does it change predictably? Please add some more info...

Comment: Data is huge in size is around 0.2 millions , Data is structured and fits in tables, data changes periodically based on the agency needs. I am not thinking about packaging as of now though the data is in structure and placed in the table. This data is used to show on the  UI for selections in the combo box/drop down in LWC.

Comment: You say that "data changes periodically based on the agency needs".  Does every org needs to receive/see all these changes?

Comment: Yes it is. considering data changes will happen may be monthly / half quarterly / yearly

Comment: You should look into External Objects, but that will require manual configuration in each org.

Comment: We may end up with API limit in the salesforce if lot of request is happening that is my concern